# Issue with Azure domain purchasing process

Tags: azure

I am trying to learn how to use Azure's web app services to set up a custom domain, but I am getting a consistent issue with it think I don't have a paid subscription. I am on the "Shared" service level and have a Pay-As-You-Go subscription, yet when I try to click the "Buy Domains" button in the Web App dashboard for my application it automatically shows me a screen "To buy a custom domain, you must have a paid Azure subscription." I have been try to refresh and reconfigure all the options related to my subscription, but it won't seem to let me buy a domain. Are the subscriptions I have not sufficient to do this?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Azure's support? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/support/options/

Comment: I don't have a support plan,  and every mechanism I was able to find to contact them directly seemed to ask me to buy one.

Comment: @Noah - billing support is free. And you can open a support ticket from the Azure portal.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Hopefully that will help resolve it, I appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question, it is a subscription question

Comment: Were you able to sort this out ? Im sitting with the same problem. Posted pretty much the same question you did on this site and no one really helps. Ive also submitted a support request and requested for Microsoft to contact me through their contact page on the azure website, so i hope they can also help...

Comment: So I don't remember the details as this was quite a while ago, but basically it turned out that I hadn't actually switched to Pay-As-You-Go. There was something where I had created the subscription, but the site was still linked to the free version from Azure. Once I got the right association, I could buy a domain. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem. I had just signed up for a new azure account and then converted my subscription from free-trial to pay-as-you-go. Somehow this doesn't propagate correctly because the subscription still showed the free trial credit. I filed a ticket with MS Support, and received an actual phone call back from a support person. They resolved it behind the scenes. Credit disappeared, but my subscription was successfully now showing pay-as-you-go in the portal.

Successfully buying a domain through the portal is another challenge though.

Answer (score -1):

Are you the Service-Admin or Co-Admin?
It might be an operation only Service-Admin can execute.